# How to Append String to start and end at given line

Tags: bash, shell

for documentation need i have a shell scripts, where i have to add certain string at the start and end in the shell scripts in a given line,  the line number is random and contain in the list

```
for example :-  
test.sh 
line number := 2,5,6,7,9
Add "&gt" "/&gt"

in test.sh file go to the line number 2 and add "&gt" in the start of the line and "/&gt" at the end of the line do the same for line number 5,6,7,9
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Your example code isn't valid Bash. You can improve the quality of your question by writing some valid Bash, attempting to solve your problem, and then updating your original post with a specific question rather than a request for someone else to write a script for you.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks no homework, i'm looking  for a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i~ '2{s/^.*$/"\&gt"&"\\\&gt"/}' FILE
```

Here `2` is line number. `"\&gt"` and `"\\\&gt"` are prefix and suffix respectively(You need to escape `&` and `\`). You will have a backup file suffixed with `~`.

Answer (score 1):

In awk, you can test if `NR` is `in` an array of line numbers returned by `patsplit()`.

Comment: `patsplit()` requires GNU AWK (`gawk`) version 4.